# Implementing use of 'with object() as f' in custom class in python

Tags: python, file-io, with-statement

I have to open a file-like object in python (it's a serial connection through /dev/) and then close it. This is done several times in several methods of my class. How I WAS doing it was opening the file in the constructor, and then closing it in the destructor. I'm getting weird errors though and I think it has to do with the garbage collector and such, I'm still not used to not knowing exactly when my objects are being deleted =\

The reason I was doing this is because I have to use `tcsetattr` with a bunch of parameters each time I open it and it gets annoying doing all that all over the place. So I want to implement an inner class to handle all that so I can use it doing
`with Meter('/dev/ttyS2') as m:`

I was looking online and I couldn't find a really good answer on how the `with` syntax is implemented. I saw that it uses the `__enter__(self)` and `__exit(self)__` methods. But is all I have to do implement those methods and I can use the with syntax? Or is there more to it?

Is there either an example on how to do this or some documentation on how it's implemented on file objects already that I can look at?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Those methods are pretty much all you need for making the object work with `with` statement.

In `__enter__` you have to return the file object after opening it and setting it up.

In `__exit__` you have to close the file object. The code for writing to it will be in the `with` statement body.

```
MODE = 'rb'
class Meter():
    def __init__(self, dev):
        self.dev = dev
    def __enter__(self):
        #ttysetattr etc goes here before opening and returning the file object
        self.fd = open(self.dev, MODE)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback):
        #Exception handling here
        self.fd.close()

meter = Meter('/dev/tty0')
with meter as m:
    #here you work with the file object.
    m.fd.read()
```

Comment: `def __enter__(self): return self` if you want a reference to `Meter` in the with block.

Comment: what is the name of such objects?

Comment: @Gulzar Those are called "Context Managers", as you enter them opening a new context and then they get their `__exit__` method called before an error is handled or when the context finishes running. So they manage the context.

Comment: Note that you need to return `True` from `__exit__` if you want to suppress the thrown error if there is any.

Answer (score 77):

Easiest may be to use standard Python library module [contextlib](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html):

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def themeter(name):
    theobj = Meter(name)
    try:
        yield theobj
    finally:
        theobj.close()  # or whatever you need to do at exit


# usage
with themeter('/dev/ttyS2') as m:
    # do what you need with m
    m.read()
```

This doesn't make `Meter` itself a context manager (and therefore is non-invasive to that class), but rather "decorates" it (not in the sense of Python's "decorator syntax", but rather almost, but not quite, in the sense of the decorator design pattern;-) with a factory function `themeter` which *is* a context manager (which the `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator builds from the "single-`yield`" generator function you write) -- this makes it **so** much easier to separate the entering and exiting condition, avoids nesting, &c.

Comment: This is much simpler than the class-based approach.

Comment: To ensure `theobj.close()` is executed even in case of an exception, you can wrap `yield theobj` with a `try...finally` block.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Not only is it simpler, but it's also cleaner to implement. I was also able to get chatgpt to refactor my code quickly to use this library, given that I had multiple embedded `with` statements.

Answer (score -15):

The first Google hit (for me) explains it simply enough:

http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

and the PEP explains it more precisely (but also more verbosely):

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: I actually saw those and didn't think either of them were very clear at all. The first pretty much says "There are methods called \__enter__ and \__exit__ " and explains little to nothing about them. And the PEP pretty much just talks about the need for the new syntax

Comment: No, it's straightforward with examples and explanations.  You need to read it again; this is not a complex feature.

Comment: Regardless, you should know that link-only answers are poorly received by the community at large. At least share something from the source that supports your assertions.

Comment: first link is dead