# How do I save multiple screenshots with same name in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I'm trying to save a screenshot with the same name for example, "Screen" and then if it already exists, save as "Screen1" and "Screen2" and so on.

This is my code:

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("Screen.png")
```

Comment: This post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852700/create-file-but-if-name-exists-add-number

Basically, check if the file you are trying to create already exists, if it does increment the filename. Or use the `tempfile` functionality builtin to python to generate unique names.

Comment: The much better way to do this would be to put a date/time stamp in the file name. That way you won't get any name collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions) you can find more information about it. You could use a while loop and check for every name (Screen1, Screen2, ...), whether it exists or not. A short example:

```
import os.path

i = 1
while True:
    fname = "Screen" + str(i) + ".png"
    if not os.path.isfile(fname):
        break
    i += 1
print(fname)
```

You could also store the current `i` and use it when saving a screenshot, this might be more efficient than this approach.