# Copying files of the same name from multiple directories into one directory

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to copy multiple files of the same name from different directories into one and have them not overwrite each other by adding some number before the name. I have a file structure like this, where the image.fits files are different files, but have the same name because they are automatically generated and the parent folder name is also auto generated:

```
~/Sources/<unknown>/<foldername1>/image.fits
~/Sources/<unknown>/<foldername2>/image.fits
~/Sources/<unknown>/<foldername3>/image.fits
...
```

Is there a way to copy these files into one folder like this:

```
~/Sources/<target_folder>/1_image.fits
~/Sources/<target_folder>/2_image.fits
~/Sources/<target_folder>/3_image.fits
```

Like mentioned above the folder names are also automatically generated, so I want to use some kind of wildcard (*) to access them if possible.
The command can either be some command, a shell script or python code, whatever works.

EDIT:
The final solution I used is based on the one from @Kasper and looks like this:

```
import os
import shutil

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system('mkdir ~/Sources/out')
    child_dirs = next(os.walk('~/Sources/'))[1]
    num=1
    for dir in child_dirs:
        child_child_dirs = next(os.walk('~/Sources/{}'.format(dir)))[1]
        for ch_dir in child_child_dirs:
            if exists('~/Sources/{}/{}'.format(dir, ch_dir))==True:
                shutil.move('~/Sources/{}/{}'.format(dir, ch_dir), '~/Sources/out/{}_image.fits'.format(num))
                num+=1
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: Check out: [Create file but if name exists add number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852700/create-file-but-if-name-exists-add-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the magic:

```
import os
import shutil

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child_dirs = next(os.walk('.'))[1]
    os.mkdir('out')
    num = 1
    for dir in child_dirs:
        shutil.copy2('{}/image.fits'.format(dir), 'out/{}_image.fits'.format(num))
        num+=1
```

It does the following:

1. Gets the current child folders.
2. Creates a new folder called `out`.
3. Loops over the folder child folders and copies the files to the new folders.

Note: the script should be ran on the parent folder.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this so it works from a different folder?
Something like: shutil.copy2('{}/{}/image.fits' ...

Comment: Yeah, you can only change the path of the `out` folder and the source path. 
Changes should be something like: 1) `child_dirs = next(os.walk(path))[1]` 2) `os.mkdir('{}/out'.format(path))` 3) `shutil.copy2('{}/{}/image.fits'.format(path,dir), '{}/out/{}_image.fits'.format(path,num))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
TARGET_FOLDER_NAME="<target_folder>"
TARGET_FILE_NAME="image.fits"

mkdir -p ~/Sources/$TARGET_FOLDER_NAME/

COUNT=1
find ~/Sources/ -type f -name $TARGET_FILE_NAME | while IFS= read -r -d '' file;
do
    mv $file ~/Sources/$TARGET_FOLDER_NAME/$COUNT_$TARGET_FILE_NAME
    COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
done
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but if you're not going to quote the names (eg `mv "${file}" ...`) there is not much point in using `-print0`.  The main reason to use `-print0` is to avoid issues with whitespace and special characters in the file names, but that benefit is lost if the names are not consistently quoted.

Answer (score 0):

This two-line solution, which doesn't require any programming, is not exactly what you want, but should be close enough, assuming you have `cp` from GNU coreutils, which is highly probable since the question is tagged with ubuntu-18.04.

```
shopt -s globstar
cp --backup=numbered Sources/**/image.fits target_folder/
```

Answer (score 0):

It is supper easy

#### first

save your file in an array

```bash
mapfile -t files < <(find a b c d e -type f -name \*.txt)
```

#### Second

```bash
# dry-run
COUNTER=0
for file in ${files[*]}; do ((++COUNTER)); echo  $file dist/${COUNTER}-${file##*/}; done
```

output:

```bash
a/file.txt dist/1-file.txt
b/file.txt dist/2-file.txt
c/file.txt dist/3-file.txt
d/file.txt dist/4-file.txt
e/file.txt dist/5-file.txt
```

#### thrid

```bash
# safe run
# cp not mv
COUNTER=0
for file in ${files[*]}; do ((++COUNTER)); cp $file dist/${COUNTER}-${file##*/}; done
```

#### last

Delete your files after checking your destination directory

---

Or one line:

```bash
COUNTER=0; for file in {a,b,c,d,e}/*; do ((++COUNTER)); echo $file dist/${COUNTER}-${file##*/}; done
```

Replace `echo` with `cp` or `mv`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

new_dir="<target_folder>"
mkdir -p "$HOME/Sources/$new_dir/"
find "$HOME/Sources/" -type f -name 'image.fits' | while read -r fileName; do
    mv "$fileName" "$HOME/Sources/$new_dir/$((n++))_${fileName##*/}"
done
```