# Using the Python WITH statement to create temporary variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, with-statement

Suppose I have Pandas data. Any data. I import `seaborn` to make a colored version of the correlation between varibales. Instead of passing the correlation expression into the heatmap fuction, and instead of  creating a one-time variable to store the correlation output, how can I use the `with` statement to create temporary variable that no longer existss after the heatmap is plotted?

**Doesn't work**

```
# Assume: season = sns, Data is heatmapable
with mypandas_df.correlation(method="pearson") as heatmap_input:
    # possible other statements
    sns.heatmap(heatmap_input)
    # possible other statements
```

If this exissted, then after seaborn plots the map, `heatmap_input` no longer exists as a variable. I would like tat functionality.

**Long way**

```
# this could be temporary but is now global
tcbtbing = mypandas_df.correlation(method="pearson")
sns.heatmap(tcbtbing)
```

**Compact way**

```
sns.heatmap( mypandas_df.correlation(method="pearson") )
```

I'd like to use the `with` statement (or similar **short**) construction to avoid the Long Way and the Compact way, but leave room for other manipulations, such as to the plot itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement **enter** and **exit** for the class you want to use it. 
see: [Implementing use of 'with object() as f' in custom class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774328/implementing-use-of-with-object-as-f-in-custom-class-in-python)

Comment: Wow. That looks quite horrible. Thanks for the insight. It would be too much rigmarole though. Especially since I'm not using it on a custom object of my own.