# object created with 'with' returns 'None'

Tags: python, class, with-statement, contextmanager

I'm trying to program a simple bank system. I should mention that I am a bit of a Python noob. For this, I have written an 'Account' class.
This is the important part of the code:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, _key, name, money):
        self.key = _key
        self.name = name
        self.money = money
        self.listhistory = [['start',
                             self.money,
                             datetime.datetime.now()
                             ]]

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.key)

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f'{self.__class__.__name__}('
                f'{self.key},'
                f'{self.name},'
                f'{self.money})')
```

When I use

```
import bank


with bank.Account(1, 'name1', 500) as name1:

    pass

with bank.Account(2, 'name2', 500) as name2:
    pass
```

, the code executes without an Error, but 'name1' and 'name2' are both 'None'. Shouldn't they be references of the object? I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing use of 'with object() as f' in custom class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774328/implementing-use-of-with-object-as-f-in-custom-class-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the [documentation for `__enter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__):

> The with statement will bind **this method’s return value** to the target(s) specified in the `as` clause of the statement, if any.

You aren't returning anything though from `__enter__`. Return `self` from it:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self
```