# TarFile.extractfile() as context manager raises 'AttributeError: __enter__'

Tags: python, tar, tarfile

Here is the relevant code:

```
for file in files:
    with readfile(file) as openfile:
        molecules.append(process_file_fn(openfile))
```

and I am getting this error from the code above:

`src/datamodules/components/edm/process.py", line 92, in process_xyz_files with readfile(file) as openfile: AttributeError: __enter__`

Here is the definition of the readfile:

```
if tarfile.is_tarfile(data):
    tardata = tarfile.open(data, "r")
    files = tardata.getmembers()
    
    def readfile(data_pt):
        return tardata.extractfile(data_pt)
```

My data is 1234.xyz.tar.bz2

Any insights/suggestions for me is appreciated. Thank you in advance

I tried to define the mode which is read in both the function and the loop but I am met with the same error.

Comment: This might be useful: [Explaining Python's `__enter__` and `__exit__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/).

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427729/python-error-attributeerror-enter) too

Comment: Your code looks weird. You are trying to use context manager, but you are also using explicit open which is what we're trying to avoid with context managers.

Comment: If you want to write your [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) I would recommend you to use the decorator [`@contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestion. However, My def readfile is inside another def called def process_file. How do I define a class in that case?

Comment: Why do you want to use `readfile` as a context manager instead of a direct call `openfile = readfile(file)`?

Comment: @DarkKnight readfile is a function. Here is the code: def readfile(data_pt): return tardata.extractfile(data_pt)

Comment: The variable names are a bit confusing here: `files` actually contains *members* of a tar archive, which are represented as `TarInfo` instances.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you don't need a context manager for your usage case.
I think you can write a direct call: `openfile = readfile(file)`.

If you really need a context manager, you can define your function like so:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def readfile(data_pt): yield tardata.extractfile(data_pt)
```

The decorator [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) will define the methods [`__enter__`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__enter__) and [`__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__exit__) for you.

Comment: Thanks alot. I tried your suggestion of writing a direct call however how do I write return tardata.extractfile(data_pt) or return openfile() on that?

Comment: @Ruby Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. I think your code works but I get this error "    xyz_lines = [line.decode("UTF-8") for line in datafile.readlines()]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readlines'"
I think this error mean it's not returning the extracted file?
I implemented the function with context manager

Comment: To answer you I will need to see your code. Please edit your question providing code enough for us to repeat the error get. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a class with the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to use a `with` statement like that.

Have a look at the responses here: [Implementing use of 'with object() as f' in custom class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774328/implementing-use-of-with-object-as-f-in-custom-class-in-python)

If you don't want to implement the context manager you could try changing your for loop to:

```py
for file in files:
    openfile = readfile(file)
    molecules.append(process_file_fn(openfile))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My def readfile is inside another def called def process_file. How do I define a class in that case?

Comment: You'd probably want to refactor your code to do that, though you could just write the class where your function is. But from reading through the other answers/comments, Jorge Luis's suggestion might be best. If you're writing this as a one off for a piece of analysis you can probably get away with a simpler solution.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @s_pike. I used Jorge Luis' contextlib code but I get this error "xyz_lines = [line.decode("UTF-8") for line in datafile.readlines()] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readlines'" I think this error mean it's not returning the extracted file?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Looks like a different error now. Follow Jorge's suggestion of creating a minimal, reproducible example - it not only helps others solve the issue, it will also help you understand your code better, and maybe even fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but here goes anyway...

You could write your own context manager class that would handle a single tar file. For the sake of simplicity we'll assume that all we want to do is extract a known member of the archive. Thus our class could look like this:

```
import tarfile

class TarfileHandler:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        self._fd = None
    @property
    def fd(self):
        if self._fd is None:
            self._fd = tarfile.open(self._filename)
        return self._fd
    def extract(self, member):
        try:
            return self.fd.extractfile(member)
        except Exception:
            pass
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *_):
        if self._fd:
            self._fd.close()
            self._fd = None
```

Now let's contrive a use-case. We know where the tar file is. We know that it contains 'foo.txt'. We want to extract 'foo.txt' and copy it somewhere.

```
TARFILE = 'mytarfile.tar'
MEMBER = 'foo.txt'
TARGET = 'foo.txt'

with TarfileHandler(TARFILE) as tfh:
    if data := tfh.extract(MEMBER):
        with open(TARGET, 'wb') as out:
            out.write(data.read())
```

Hopefully this shows you how to implement a context manager class and how you might adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

So far, none of the other answers have explained what is actually causing the `AttributeError: __enter__`.

#### Cause

What it boils down to is that the OP is trying to use the *return value* from [`TarFile.extractfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers).

However, the value returned by [`TarFile.extractfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) can be ***either*** an `io.BufferedReader` ***or*** `None`:

> ... If *member* is a regular file or a link, an [`io.BufferedReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader) object is returned. For all other existing members, `None` is returned. ...

See how this is implemented in the `tarfile` [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/456e274578dc9863f42ab24d62adc0d8c511b50f/Lib/tarfile.py#L2394).

Although the `BufferedReader` [***can***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) be used as a context manager, `None` obviously ***cannot***.

So, the `AttributeError: __enter__` will occur, for example, if you call `extractfile()` on a member that represents a directory.

#### Solution

A workaround for the OP's example could be to [check if the member is actually a file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarInfo.isfile):

```py
for file in files:
    if file.isfile():  # <-- NEW
        with readfile(file) as openfile:
            ...
```

Note that `files = tardata.getmembers()`, in the OP's example, implies that `file` is actually an archive *member*, in the form of a [`TarInfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarinfo-objects) instance. To avoid confusion, I would rename to `members` and `member`, respectively.

Comment: The question remains whether it is actually necessary to close the `BufferedReader`, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/9718950.